# How can I access unnamed elements from an HTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set `float` values for the first three `li` present in my HTML using javascript. I have named the parent `ul` as "something". Is it possible to set the float attribute for these `li` without naming them?

Comment: could you please paste in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can find the unnamed li elements in pure javascript using this snippet:

```
var children = document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Where something is the name of the parent.

Then you access the first three children as usual

```
children[0].style.float = "left";
children[1].style.float = "left";
children[2].style.float = "left";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#something : nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
}

#something : nth-child(2) {
    float: left;        
}

#something : nth-child(3) {
    float: left;        
}
```

Might do what you want...

Comment: You beat me to it by 31s so you can have my jsfiddle if you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/h7aVK/

Comment: +1 for using CSS, but the OP said "named 'something'" so # selector might not be correct. The name attribute is not standard for UL elements.

Comment: I needed to do this during runtime, so thats why I wanted to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elems = document.getElementById("something").getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    elems[i].style.float = "left;
}
```

Comment: this will get every li on the page

Answer (score 0):

you can use getElementByTagName function

eg:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getElementsByName` and `.getElementsByTagName`.

See:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function f () {
    var objUl = document.getElementsByName("Test")[0];
    var lstLi = objUl.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
      lstLi[i].style.color = "red";
    }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<ul name="Test">
 <li> One </li>
 <li> Two </li>
 <li> Three </li>
 <li> Four </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="f()" value="Click me" />
</body>
</html>
```

I use `style.color` here for illustrative purposes. Obviously, you'd want to use `style.float = "left"` to float them left.